# Use listView to change songs in android mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-listview, media-player

I apologize if this is a repeat, but my research has come up empty in finding stuff pertinent to this specific case.

I'm trying to create an application where the user clicks a button in an activity and is prompted with a listView in another activity with the titles of songs as the content. When the user clicks on a listView item, the corresponding song (saved in the Raw file) will play. Assume the songs are named song1, song2, etc, for now. I have the app working up to choosing the song. They are prompted with the listview which correctly displays the titles, but I'm stuck as to what to do from this point.

So basically, I need help with handling the user click on any given item to play that song in the original activity.

Code for the Main Activity:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {


//set view to the home screen
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

}   

//Show the Activity for the song list
public void showSongList (View clickedButton) {
    // the showSongList is defined in the layout xml file. 
    Intent switchScreen = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, SongList.class);
    startActivity(switchScreen);
}
}
```

Code for the Activity with the listView

```
public class SongList extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Store the string resources into the array
    String[] music_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.songs);
    //Binding resources array into adapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, music_list));

}

}
```

This is the XML for the string array which the list is based off of

```
<resources>
<string-array name="songs">
    <!-- Go back will be defined later to return to the original Activity -->
    <item>Go Back</item>
    <item>First Song</item>
    <item>Second Song</item>
    <item>Third Song</item>
    <item>Fourth Song</item>
    <item>Fifth Song</item>
    <item>Sixth Song</item>
    <item>Seventh Song</item>
    <item>Eighth Song</item>
    <item>Ninth Song</item>
    <item>Tenth Song</item>
    <item>Eleventh Song</item>
    <item>Twelfth Song</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

I apologize that this is probably an easy question for someone who knows what they're doing.

If there is any extra code that needs posted, Just ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any code that actually plays the music? Because from what i see, you are only moving from one activity to another, and displaying a listview. There is no Mediaplayer.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure how to use it in this case. I've done it before, but just not from a list.  I'm just not sure in what code to initiate/run it and how to call it from the list items.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `setonitemClickListener` to your listview. **In the listener, you will get the song's posision in the listview.** So you can know the song selected by user and play the music.
As for the code of playing music, I'm sorry that I havent used.
By the way, if you need add or remove songs, getting the songs list by file may be better.

> mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>       @Override
>       public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
>       //arg2 means the chosen songs posision. You can control your play here with the parameter
> }
>       });

In you code, the **mListView** is **this**.

Comment: Sorry about the late response, but could you use an example of syntax for that method?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task use the onItemClickListener. set it on your list view and use the position argument in onItemClick() to get the position of each item clicked. Then pass it to any method which will resolve the position and play the song by creating its object.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)          {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    i = arg2;
    musicPlay(b1);


}

public void musicPlay(View v){

        int id=0;
        if(i==0){
            id=R.raw.abc;
        }
        if(i==1){
            id=R.raw.abcde;
        }
        if(i==2){
            id=R.raw.gghi;
        }
        if(mp==null){
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, id);
            mp.start();
        }
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, id);
        mp.start();

}
```

Here use i as an global integer variable.
Hope this helps.